# float: left not working as expected

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here's the link: http://www.iancreates.com/3dbikefit/

The divs `.pod` have the following CSS:

```
.pod {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.898438);
border-bottom-right-radius: 15px 15px;
border-top-left-radius: 15px 15px;
color: black;
float: left;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 15px;
width: 270px;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is 'expected'? float in one line?

Comment: First... What was your expectation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your container div only has a width of 550px, so your pods won't fit in. 270+15+15 = 300px width... so only 1 can fit in that 550px.  You most likely want to move it outside of the container div.

Answer (score 1):

Padding is your problem. The container they sit in is limited to 550px. You've added 15px both to the left and right on your pods. This makes the total width of each 300px. Since they're limited to 550px they stack. You need to reduce the total width+padding on the pods or increase the width of the container.